# Cache.match API ignores request object headers?

Tags: caching, http-headers, service-worker

I'm programming a service-worker in order to to cache responses from an API in case of bad internet connection. I'm using `cache.put` to store the request object and the response object, and `cache.match` to retrieve the cached response.
What I noticed is that giving the same request with two different `accepted-language` headers, the cache.match always return to me the last cached response.

Here's an example time ordered:

**NETWORK ON (response are fetched from server)**

```
request:
GET
/presentation
accepted-language: en

response:
Hi!

request:
GET
/presentation
accepted-language: es

response:
Ola!
```

**NETWORK OFF (response are fetched by cache object)**

```
request:
GET
/presentation
accepted-language: en

response:
Olà! //WRONG!

request:
GET
/presentation
accepted-language: es

response:
Ola!
```

**NETWORK ON (response are fetched from server)**

```
request:
GET
/presentation
accepted-language: es

response:
Ola!

request:
GET
/presentation
accepted-language: en

response:
Hi!
```

**NETWORK OFF (response are fetched by cache object)**

```
request:
GET
/presentation
accepted-language: en

response:
Hi!

request:
GET
/presentation
accepted-language: es

response:
Hi! //WRONG!
```

What I assume is that the cache.match api ignores http headers when matching. Is that right? Then if I want to overcome this, should I generate a fake URL string with the headers trasposed as querystring to store/retrieve the responses?